# I can't get the Nvidia driver to work, anyone any ideas?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

How can I install my Nvidia GT735m drivers. My laptop has optimus technology with a HD4000 as powersaving gpu besides the nvidia card. But I can´t get my gt735m to work. Everytime I try to install it I get a black screen after a reboot (which is unfixable, and if I manage to get the desktop interface back I can only run a 640x800 res.)

So... does anyone has a idea how to install this nvidia driver?

(ps. is it possible to disable my HD4000 and only run the nvidia card for everything including the desktop?)

Comment: Is not installing the Nvidia drivers an option?

Answer (score 0):

can you give more information about what you have tried (to fix the black screen in particular) did you already try the suggestions in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/a/162076/146890)?

I don't have a optimus video card but I believe [bumblebee](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee) is a project that is working on optimus support.

in general how you install drivers that are not standard included in ubuntu is this: go to system settings, go to 'software & Updates' open the 'Additional Drivers' tab let it search for proprietary drivers and have a look whether you can activate a driver.